# Release date for Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud

We are very interested in leveraging Spring cloud Sleuth for our project and are interested in learning about the release date. Any visibility into your roadmap will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout our milestones https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/milestones

Dates aren't firm.